# Printing range of lines determined by variables with sed returns invalid command code

Tags: macos, shell, variables, unix, sed

I'm trying to print a range of lines determined by two variables set outside the script. For some reason I keep getting the invalid command code error. If I set the variables inside the script (using `FT_LINE1=7` for example) it works just fine, but if the variables are set outside it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my full script:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep -v "#" | sed '1d; n; d' | sed 's/:\*:.*//' | rev | sort -r |
    sed -n "$FT_LINE1,${FT_LINE2}p"
```

The error I receive is:

> sed: 1: ",p": invalid command code ,

I am using MacOS.

Comment: I set them before I run the shell file. Is this the problem? The reason I did it this way is that the exercise requires the following (rough translation): _Write a script that prints from the results of a 'cat /etc/passwd' the logins between FT_LINE1 and FT_LINE2... [other instructions e.g: invert the lines, reverse sort etc.]_ If the variables are set inside the script how can the correction program verify that the script works as intended?

Comment: The scope of those variables isn't going to make it into the script unless they're environment variables.  The script can take command line arguments, or use environment variables, but it cannot pull shell variables from a different shell process.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. All I had to do was to export the variables to the environment before running the script. This can be done with `export FT_LINE1`.